# python - scraping tables with dependent dropdown lists

Tags: python, selenium, dropdownlistview

I am trying to obtain the electoral results of the 2016 elections in Peru disaggregated by district. As you can see in this link (https://www.web.onpe.gob.pe/modElecciones/elecciones/elecciones2016/PRPCP2016/Resultados-Ubigeo-Presidencial.html#posicion), when selecting the "scope", three boxes appear more with the title of "department", "province" and "district". I want to extract all the results from the image table at the "district" level and save them in a table, but to achieve this I must first select "department", "province" and "district" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Z7H.png)

So far, I have written this code that inserts options determined by me to dropdown lists, but I was wondering if I can automate the selection of options. There are 1874 districts so doing it manually is not an option.

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.web.onpe.gob.pe/modElecciones/elecciones/elecciones2016/PRPCP2016/Resultados-Ubigeo-Presidencial.html#posicion')
time.sleep(4)

selectAmbit = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("cdgoAmbito"))
selectAmbit.select_by_value('P')

time.sleep(2)

selectRegion = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("cdgoDep"))
selectRegion.select_by_value('010000')

time.sleep(2)

selectProvin = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("cdgoProv"))
selectProvin.select_by_value('010200')

time.sleep(2)

selectDistr = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("cdgoDist"))
selectDistr.select_by_value('010202')
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop to get all selectDistr options. You'd just do it nested to select all options of every type .

```
selectDistr = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("cdgoDist"))

for option in selectDistr.options:
    selectDistr.select_by_value(option.get_attribute('value'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you help me by giving me some notion of how to save each of the loop results in a table or multiple tables? I want to take them to a CSV